# Installing TensorFlow serving without using a docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow-serving

To the best of my efforts, I have found that there is no way to install TensorFlow serving without using a docker.  Is the use of a docker firmly embedded with TensorFlow Serving or is there a workaround ?

Comment: It should be perfectly possible to install it without Docker: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/setup.md

Answer (score 1):

You can install TensorFlow serving without using a docker:

- Building from source
- TensorFlow Serving Python API PIP package

  pip install tensorflow-serving-api

You can install TensorFlow serving using any of the following 3 ways :

- Installing using Docker
- Building from source
- TensorFlow Serving Python API PIP package

  pip install tensorflow-serving-api

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/setup#tensorflow_serving_python_api_pip_package

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/setup.md